# Repeated countdown timer with rounds display

Tags: java, android, timer

I am making repeated countdown timer and when I set for example 2 rounds and after that I would like to see "finish" when on display I get 2/2 . I tried make it like in code below but it doesn't work. I marked by ** the area I mean

```
 final Context cntx=this;
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int num_rounds=0;
            try {
                num_rounds = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(cntx,"Invalid Integer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;}
            if(num_rounds==0)
            {
                return;
            }
            final int[] round_count = {0};
            final int finalNum_rounds = num_rounds;
            CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    tv1.setText((round_count[0]+1)+"/"+finalNum_rounds+" "+(int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));

                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    round_count[0]++;
                    if(round_count[0] < finalNum_rounds){
                        Handler handler=new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                start();
                            }
                        },5000);
                    }

                      ***
                    if (!tv1.equals(finalNum_rounds+"/"+finalNum_rounds )){
                        tv1.setText("Finish");
                    }
                       ***
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: did your text in tv1 is finalNum_rounds+"/"+finalNum_rounds?? because you settext like this.`tv1.setText((round_count[0]+1)+"/"+finalNum_rounds+" "+(int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));`

Comment: My text view look like that " tv1.setText((round_count[0]+1)+"/"+finalNum_rounds+" "+(int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));" but after seconds round from 2 rounds I would like to set "fininsh"

Comment: yes. your text show llike `(round_count[0]+1)+"/"+finalNum_rounds+" "+(int) (millisUntilFinished/1000)`. but your condition is `finalNum_rounds+"/"+finalNum_rounds`